# Remove stopwords or exclusion list while retrieving data from elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, dsl

- I need to remove stop words and some words to exclude to search
- if i m searching for comedy i should not get anything since its in exclusion list, i have added comedy in stopwords
- what word i have added in stop words then i should not get that if it's matches irrespective of
- if i am doing normal search then i should return the values present. like if i m searching for `Jennifer`
- RIght now stopwords is not working for me, if i m searching `and` i m getting output, but i should not
- I have to use `query_string` only in my dsl query

`[ { 'id': 0, 'Title': 'Live1', 'US Gross': 146083, 'Worldwide Gross': 146083, 'US DVD Sales': None, 'Production Budget': 8000000, 'Release Date': 'Jun 12 1998', 'MPAA Rating': 'R', 'Running Time min': None, 'Distributor': 'Gramercy', 'Source': None, 'Major Genre': Comedy, 'Creative Type': None, 'Director': T and I, 'Rotten Tomatoes Rating': None, 'IMDB Rating': 6.1, 'IMDB Votes': 1071 }, { 'id': 1, 'Title': 'First Love, Last Rites', 'US Gross': 10876, 'Worldwide Gross': 10876, 'US DVD Sales': None, 'Production Budget': 300000, 'Release Date': 'Aug 07 1998', 'MPAA Rating': 'R', 'Running Time min': None, 'Distributor': 'Strand', 'Source': None, 'Major Genre': 'Drama', 'Creative Type': None, 'Director': Richard Jennifer, 'Rotten Tomatoes Rating': None, 'IMDB Rating': 6.9, 'IMDB Votes': 207 }]`

settings is below

```
settings =   {
 "settings": {
   "analysis": {
     "analyzer": {
       "blogs_analyzer": {
         "type": "standard",
         "stopwords": ["and", "is","comedy"]
       }
     }
   }
 }
}
```

My Dsl query is below

```
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "and",
          "fields": ["Title^24",
            "Major Genre^8","Director^2" ]
        }
      }
    }
  }}
```

Comment: Can you please add index mapping as well  for field which you want to search on

Comment: i am searching on Title, Director Major Genre

Comment: You have not given field name in `query_string` so it will search on other field as well. Did you applied `blogs_analyzer` on title field in mapping ?

Comment: @SagarPatel, where i should add that, i have updated DSL query with fields

Comment: Can you do `GET index_name` and check what is analyzer applied on `title` field.

Comment: this is the only setting i have i m pasting the get mappings  `{'data': {'settings': {'index': {'number_of_shards': '1',
    'provided_name': 'data',
    'creation_date': '1655400993201',
    'analysis': {'analyzer': {'blogs_analyzer': {'type': 'standard',
       'stopwords': ['and', 'is', 'comedy']}}},
    'number_of_replicas': '1',
    'uuid': 'rRlAiWm0QUqqNQPW9N29hw',
    'version': {'created': '7080099'}}}}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have created `blogs_analyzer` but not assign to any of the field. So it will consider standard analyzer.

You need to create index mapping with below configuration and then it will not give you result:

```json
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "blogs_analyzer": {
          "type": "standard",
          "stopwords": [
            "and",
            "is",
            "comedy"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "Title": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "blogs_analyzer"
      },
      "Director": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "blogs_analyzer"
      },
      "Major Genre": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "blogs_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

After above configuration, you can reindex your data and search with below query:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "fields": ["Title","Director","Major Genre"], 
      "query": "and"
    }
  }
}
```